# Reading from a USB

Tags: usb

I had UBUNTU 18.04 just yesterday. I found every thing I expected except how to use a USB. Any USB i insert is not sensed and files on it do not appear. I tried HELP but so far could not find an answer. How to read files from a USB.
Thank you.

Comment: did you see your USB device inside `/media` ?

Comment: You could always load 'disks' (or `gnome-disks`) where you see drives & partitions, and `mount` the wanted 'thumb drive'.  I installed a thumb-drive on my system & it reports it with brand & model of thumb-drive providing a 'play' type symbol (telling me it means "mount selected" in text when I hover over it). Also provided are 'stop' (unmount) & 'power-off' functions...  (*I don't use GNOME, and `mount` usually via terminal; when I clicked 'mount' it mount in /media/$USER/.. as damadam suggested*)

Comment: If you are using ubuntu 18.04 you are also using Gnome. So try with gnome-disks. (it is there or install it from the repository). Eventually install g-parted.  This let you see if the usb stick are partitioned, and can be mounted.  This may be helpful.

Comment: Is USB still configured as enabled in your BIOS? Is USB shown as a BIOS boot option?